# TypeScript tries to compile node_modules of sibling folder with Yarn Workspaces

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to make a monorepo project with "server" and "client" folders using TypeScript and Yarn Workspaces. Compiling the "server" folder without having created the "client" folder yet works well, but when I create the "client" folder, compiling the "server" folder makes TypeScript wanting to compile the node_modules folder of "client", giving errors but compiling nonetheless.

The errors are like:

> ../../../../.config/yarn/global/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5353:11 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FormData'.
>
> 5353 interface FormData {
>                  ~~~~~~~~
>
> ../node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:40:15
>       40 declare class FormData {
>                        ~~~~~~~~
>   'FormData' was also declared here.
>
> ../../../../.config/yarn/global/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:5363:13 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'FormData'.
>
> 5363 declare var FormData: {
>                    ~~~~~~~~
>
> ../node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:40:15
>       40 declare class FormData {
>                        ~~~~~~~~
>   'FormData' was also declared here.
>
> ../../../../.config/yarn/global/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:15671:11 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'URLSearchParams'.
>
> 15671 interface URLSearchParams {
>                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> ../node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts:258:15
>       258 declare class URLSearchParams {
>                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   'URLSearchParams' was also declared here.

I've tried:

- not using Workspaces,
- specifying "client" as a dependency of "server",
- excluding node_modules from "server" tsconfig,

but no results.

I've created a test repo to reproduce the errors (1- clone repo, 2- yarn install, 3- cd server, 4- tsc): https://github.com/lewislbr/typescript-test

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it by:

- Installing "@types/node" as a common dev dependency,
- Adding "types": ["node"] in the common tsconfig.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the issue for me too. But you seem to be understanding it wrong. Adding a `types` property to your `compilerOptions` disables automatic inclusion, which is only important if you’re using files with global declarations (as opposed to files declared as modules), so it should be safe to disable in most projects. The `node` types are not related to your solution. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types